# Keep cell reference constant in chart with google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I've tried to use the '$' in the data range for a chart, but when I add an additional column, it changes the cells the chart is referring to to the original column.

Everyday I add a column of data to a sheet.  I just want the chart to keep referring to that newest column of data instead of referring to the previous day's column of data.

Comment: Use an indirect link to the range which picks up the newly populated cells, so you will need to check for non-empty cells. Done this in excel but you are in googlesheets even though you tagged excel.

Comment: not supported. you will need to filter your desired column on a separate sheet and from there build your chart

Comment: Excel is not Google Sheets. Please fix the question tags.

Comment: @player0 Could you elaborate? I made another sheet and made the cells on the new sheet '=' the data i want on the first sheet. But the same problem happens when I add a new column, the chart follows the data and doesn't keep reading the same column.

Comment: can you share a copy/dummy of your sheet?

Comment: I suggest you let Google know it's important to be able to do this by using the `Send feedback` option available from the Sheet UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this formula and create chart from there:

```
={INDIRECT("DF!D39:D41"), INDIRECT("DF!"&
  ADDRESS(39, MATCH(MAX(DF!1:1), DF!1:1, 0))&":"&
  ADDRESS(41, MATCH(MAX(DF!1:1), DF!1:1, 0)))}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you link the chart on tab DF to keep updating when I add columns?  Like it works...but i don't see how there's a link to what you did on sheet9?  When I add a new column E of data, the chart on tab DF says column 2 must be numeric (which is correct since theres no new data).  This is so confusing how you did this.

Comment: formula brings 1st column from your DF sheet and then 2nd column is brought by matching the max date from all the DF columns so basically it doesnt matter where you input the new column (right or left) it will always check the highest date on row 1 and bring that column over to Sheet9 from where you can construct your pie chart

Comment: You're a genius.

Answer (score 0):

Do not ad $ Mark and keep adding the columns to the left no to the Right or in between.
I tried on a chart and  it works.

Comment: The Data i use in in columns D and E.  D is the labels, E is the numbers.  Everyday I add a new column E, and it moves the old data to Column F.  I want the chart to always read the data from column E.  But when I add a new column to the left of E, the chart updates to read D and F.